# SwiftUI ForEach indices error about expected argument type Binding<C>

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach, codable

I'm getting this error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Array<Cat>.Index>' (aka 'Range<Int>') to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'
```

On this `ForEach` line:

```
ForEach(viewModel.cats.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let cat = viewModel.cat[index]
    ...
}
```

In the view model:

```
@Published var cats: [Cat] = [] {
    didSet {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

And the Cat object:

```
struct Cat: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
}
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it? I do need access to `index`.

Comment: There is a typo somewhere, comment out sections until you find it. Also you shouldn’t override Hashable unless you have a really good reason. SwiftUI will not reload with just the id because it won’t know of changes. Also indicies are considered unsafe.

Comment: As @loremipsum suggested, locating errors in Swift is still far from ideal and the line highlighted for an error is, sometimes, not the place where you would expect it. Swift is a strongly-typed language, and, not to be too annoying, the compiler has a "type inference" system, essentially, if type is not explicitly defined, it guesses what the type should be, I think this error might be related to this – different expectations of the type of the same value in different places in the code.

Comment: Regarding using indices in ForEach, the value for `id` is used as an "identity" for the content block, because of that, if you use the array index, if ordering of items within that array changes, SwiftUI view rendering system might (and frequently does) render the view hierarchy incorrectly. As the `Cat` is already `Identifiable`, you could just do this: `ForEach(viewModel.cats) { cat in`